# App badge doesn't update on getting notifications in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, push-notification

In my React Native application, i am getting notifications and i am using `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios` to update the badge on app icon when the user opens a notification. But when the app is in the background, notification comes and the badge count remains the same. It always shows 1. What can i do to fix this part. I am guessing i have to do something in `AppDelegate.m` as i am not using any other dependency for the notification. Here's what my AppDelegate.m looks like:

```js
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"Bisly";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

   [FIRApp configure];
  RCTLog(@"Some information3");
  NSLog(@"Some information4");

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  // UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  // center.delegate = self;

  // return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  RCTLog(@"Some information");
  NSLog(@"Some information2");
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler

{
  RCTLog(@"Some information1");
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}


//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}


- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  return true;
}

@end
```